# How to read from one stream and write to several at once?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pipeline, node-streams

Suppose I have a `readable` stream, e.g. `request(URL)`. And I want to write its response on the disk via `fs.createWriteStream()` and piping with the request. But at the same time I want to calculate a checksum of the downloading data via `crypto.createHash()` stream.

```
readable -+-> calc checksum
          |
          +-> write to disk
```

And I want to do it on the fly, without buffering an entire response in memory.

It seems that I can implement it using oldschool `on('data')` hook. Pseudocode below:

```
const hashStream = crypto.createHash('sha256');
hashStream.on('error', cleanup);

const dst = fs.createWriteStream('...');
dst.on('error', cleanup);

request(...).on('data', (chunk) => {
    hashStream.write(chunk);
    dst.write(chunk);
}).on('end', () => {
    hashStream.end();
    const checksum = hashStream.read();
    if (checksum != '...') {
        cleanup();
    } else {
        dst.end();
    }
}).on('error', cleanup);

function cleanup() { /* cancel streams, erase file */ };
```

But such approach looks pretty awkward. I tried to use `stream.Transform` or `stream.Writable` to implement something like `read | calc + echo | write` but I'm stuck with the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js readable streams have a `.pipe` method which works pretty much like the unix pipe-operator, except that you can stream js objects as well as just strings of some type.

[Here's a link to the doc on pipe](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options)

An example of the use in your case could be something like:

```
const req = request(...);
req.pipe(dst);
req.pipe(hash);
```

Note that you still have to handle errors per stream as they're not propagated and the destinations are not closed if the readable errors.

Comment: Thanks! Quote from the doc "It is possible to attach multiple Writable streams to a single Readable stream." This is it! I knew about `pipe()` but it looks like I missed this facility.